# List files exist in external storage directory

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to list jpg files that exist in my internal and external storage, the below code works when using Environment.getRootDirectory(), but when using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() it gives nothing and not working.

OnCreate: I added the below call:

```
walkdir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

Here is the void to list files:

```
 public void walkdir(File dir) {
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_data);
    int count=0;
    File[] listFile;
    listFile = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")){
                    tv.setText(tv.getText().toString()+"\n"+listFile[i].toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Manifest: I added these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Please anyone can advise why the code is working with getRootDirectory() and not working with getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you did not add code to request the user to confirm the read and write permission you requested in manifest.

Google for runtime permission.

Comment: could you please advise how to add the code to request the user to confirm the read and write permission

Comment: Google for runtime permissions.

Comment: For a test you can go to the settings for your app and toggle the storage toggle to ON.